# Javascript. Объект как массив. Как получить доступ к данным?

Tags: javascript

Есть:

```
steps = {
    1: {
        head : "Обучение",
        text : "<p>Добро пожаловать</p>",
        btn : {
            go: true,
            next: false,
            ntnow: true,
            done: false
        },
        point: {
            wrap: false,
            count: 0
        },
        girl: 1,
        select : { // id или false
            one : false,
            two : false
        },
        marker : { // id или false
            one : false,
            two : false
        },
        arrow : false
    }
```

Как получать из объекта правильно данные в случае если у нас внутри в названии массива присутствует число? К примеру, хочу получить данные "head", пишу:

> console.log(steps.1.head);

выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Может опечатка, но похоже что еще и `}` не закрыта в самом конце...

Comment: Ключи-цифры можно получить только через скобки `steps[1].head`. Через точку можно обращаться только к именам